# Repulsive force between electrons at relativistic speeds

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces, scattering

What happens to the repulsive force between two electrons, once one of the electrons travel at relativistic speeds?

Let's consider two electrons in an atom with magnetic dipole moment, one of which is travelling at relativistic speed $v\sim c$. If electrons were stationary in a reference frame $S$, one could use Coulomb's law to compute the repulsive force

$$\textbf{E}(r) = \frac{kq}{r^2} \hat{r}\tag{1}$$

Lorentz force generalizes this situation as

$${\displaystyle \vec{\mathbf{F}} = q\left(\vec{\mathbf{E}} +\vec{\mathbf{v}} \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} \right) = \vec{\mathbf{F}}_{\text{S}} +  \vec{\mathbf{F}}_{\text{M}}}\tag{2}$$

Magnetic field due to magnetic dipole is given by

$$\vec{\mathbf{B}}(r) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\left[ \frac{3(\vec{m}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{r}}{r^5} - \frac{\vec{m}}{r^3}\right] + \frac{2}{3}\mu_{0}\vec{m}\delta^3(r) \tag{3}$$

Whose total magnetic moment resulting from spin and orbital angular momenta of the electron is $$\vec{m} = -\frac{g_{\text{J}}\mu_{B}}{\hbar}\vec{\text{J}}\tag{4}$$

Therefore $(3)$ reads

$$\vec{\mathbf{B}}(r) = -\frac{\mu_0g_{J}\mu_{B}}{4\pi\hbar}\left[ \frac{3(\vec{\text{J}}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{r}}{r^5} - \frac{\vec{\text{J}}}{r^3}\right] - \frac{2\mu_0g_{\text{J}}\mu_{B}}{3\hbar}\vec{\text{J}}\delta^3(r)\tag{5}$$

Lorentz force in $(2)$ is then

$$\vec{\mathbf{F}}(r) = \frac{ke}{r^2} \hat{r}-\frac{\mu_0g_{\text{J}}\mu_{B}}{4\pi\hbar}\left[ \frac{3(\vec{\text{J}}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{v}\times\vec{r}}{r^5} - \frac{\vec{v}\times\vec{\text{J}}}{r^3}\right]-\frac{2\mu_0g_{\text{J}}\mu_{B}}{3\hbar}\vec{v}\times\vec{\text{J}}\delta^3(r)\tag{6}$$

Where $e, \mu_{0}, g_{\text{J}}, \mu_{B}$ denote respectively the unit charge of electron, [vacuum permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability), [Landé $g$-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land%C3%A9_g-factor), and [Bohr magneton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton).

Answer (score 1):

The Lorentz force law is already a fully relativistic equation and Lorentz covariant, which is not too surprising when you consider the Lorentz transformations of special relativity are named after him.

The vector equation ${\displaystyle \mathbf {F} = q\left(\mathbf {E} +\vec{\mathbf{v}} \times \mathbf {B}  \right).}\tag{2}$ can be rewritten in component form as:

$F_x = q(E_x +v_y Bz - v_z B_y)$
$F_y = q(E_y +v_z Bx - v_x B_z)$
$F_z = q(E_z +v_x By - v_y B_x)$

When transformed to another reference frame moving along the x-axis the equations become:

$F'_x = q(E'_x +v_y B'z - v_z B'_y)$
$F'_y = q(E'_y +v_z B'x - v_x B'_z)$
$F'_z = q(E'_z +v_x B'y - v_y B'_x)$

which is straight forward enough, but we have to substitute the primed values for the electric and magnetic field values from the unprimed frame to be useful:

$E'_x = E_x $
$E'_y =  \gamma (E_y + u B_z)$
$E'_z =  \gamma (E_z - u B_y)$

$B'_x = B_x $
$B'_y = \gamma (B_y - u E_z)$
$B'_z = \gamma (B_z + u E_y)$

where $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{(1-u^2/c^2)}$. Note that I have used u instead of the the usual v in the above transformation equations as a distinction must be made between the velocity v of the particle relative to the fields and the relative velocity u of the two reference frames. For example if the particle is moving at v>0 in the positive x direction then v becomes zero in its own rest frame, but the relative velocity u becomes -u in the new reference frame.

Electromagnetic forces transform the same way as any other force is relativity (as hey must) and the above transformations  of the force components can be abbreviated as:

$F'_x = F_x$
$F'_y = \gamma F_y$
$F'_z = \gamma F_z$

To calculate the acceleration associated with the above forces use:

$a_x = \frac{F_x}{m_0 \gamma^3}, \ \ \  a_y = \frac{F_y}{m_0 \gamma}, \ \ \ a_z = \frac{F_z}{m_0 \gamma} $

Refs: [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) and [Mathpages](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-02/2-02.htm).

As for what actually goes on inside the orbitals of an atom, there is too much quantum stuff going on there for me to come to a conclusion in that particular scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful answer. Did you mind taking a look at the things I’ve done in my question statement?

Comment: I'm afraid your approach and equations are above my pay grade :-)